# Изменять цвет заголовка при прочтении

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть список новостей, при переходе на новость открывается информация в новой активити. Пробую сделать так, что после того как пользователь прочитал новость менялся цвет заголовка.
Было принято решение заменить реализацию `SharedPreference` базой данных `SQLite`.

Первым делом создал класс `TopStoryDatabaseHelper`, где сохраняю `Id` :

```
public class TopStoryDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "topstory";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public TopStoryDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TOPSTORY("
            + " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT;) ");
    insertId(sqLiteDatabase);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

private static void insertId(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    ContentValues idValues = new ContentValues();
    sqLiteDatabase.insert("TOPSTORY", null, idValues);
    }
}
```

Логика по идее та же, пользователь кликает на новость - новость открывается - сохраняется id - после чего новость считается прочитанной - меняем цвет для прочитанной новости. 
Так как пользователь добавляет n-ое кол-во id, хотел бы уточнить
1. Нужно ли добавлять в бд все поля для моей новости?
2. После этого, как из класса активити делать выборку по id правильно.

Comment: Из приведенного Вами фрагмента кода мало что понятно.

Comment: @post_zeew у меня есть id который я сохраняю в sharedprefence после чего для каждой нажатой новости проверяю  наличие id. И если он есть, то выполняю условие.

Comment: Мой первый комментарий был к тому, что Вы показываете мало кода.

Comment: @post_zeew обновил вопрос.

Comment: А Вы для каждой новости сохраняете значение с помощью одного и того же ключа?

Comment: @post_zeew выходит что так да

Comment: Вы понимаете, что это неправильно?

Comment: @post_zeew пока если честно не очень)

Comment: Вы просмотрели новость, записали ее идентификатор, далее Вы просмотрели другую новость, записали *туда же* ее идентификатор. В итоге у Вас не будет информации о том, была ли просмотрена первая новость.

Comment: @post_zeew теперь понятно. По идее мне сейчас нужно исправить 1. сохранения для каждой новости своего ключа и только потом пробовать изменить цвет для каждой просмотренной новости?

Comment: Вам пару дней назад советовали использовать для решения Вашей задачи базы данных, Вы же почему-то игнорируете этот *правильный* способ. Хоть и решить Вашу задачу можно и с помощью `SharedPreferences`, но это решение будет *неправильным с точки зрения архитектуры*, и, если что-то изменится, Вам нужно будет все *кардинально* менять. А так да, сохраняйте состояние каждой новости с разными ключами. Работать будет... пока будет. Но это нехороший способ для решения подобного рода задач.

Comment: @post_zeew еще не созрел я для бд)) а если новостей очень много получится, как можете посоветовать их сохрнять?

Comment: То, что Вы еще не созрели для БД, вовсе не означает, что нужно решать задачи с помощью *костылей*, а означает как раз то, что пора учиться работать с базами данных. А ответ на Ваш вопрос содержится в предыдущем моем комментарии.

Answer (score 2):

1) Каждый раз при клике вы переходите к телу новости и там вы сохраняете `ID` в базе, что вы уже сделали

2) Каждый раз когда в `Activity` будете подгружать новости в `RecyclerView`, в адаптере в методе `onBindViewHolder()` будете проверять `ID Новости` которую только что с сервера подгрузили с тем `ID` который в базе. И если они равны, то меняете цвет заголовка.

Вот кусок кода для просмотренных:

Из базы получаю `ID` всех вакансии и в viewedVacanciesIDList храню.

```
SQLHelper sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(mContext);
HashSet<Integer> viewedVacanciesIDList = sqlHelper.haveWatchedVacancies();
```

где `haveWatchedVacancies()` возвращает из базы `ID` всех вакансии.

```
public HashSet<Integer> haveWatchedVacancies() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        HashSet<Integer> watchedVacanciesList = new HashSet<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(true, WATCHED.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int vacancyIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(WATCHED.KEY_VACANCY_ID);
                do {
                    int getVacancyID = cursor.getInt(vacancyIdIndex);
                    watchedVacanciesList.add(getVacancyID);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } else {
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("WATCHED TABLE", "empty db");
        }
        return watchedVacanciesList;
    }
```

А `viewedVacanciesIDList` для хранения полученных данных из базы локально, ну чтобы каждый раз при проверке не приходилось обращаться к базе, типа

```
if (sqlHelpter.haveWatchedVacancies().contains(model.getId())
```

И делаю проверку.

```
holder.vacancyViewed.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if (viewedVacanciesIDList.contains(model.getId())) {
     holder.vacancyViewed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

А вам не нужно делать невидимым, еще проще

```
if (viewedVacanciesIDList.contains(model.getId())) {
     holder.vacancyViewed.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: не могли бы пожалуйста пояснить `haveWatchedVacancies` и что за viewedVacanciesIDList его надо и в классе БД как то прописать? (+у меня recyclerView).

Comment: обновил ответ, проверьте пожалуйста